# CsvReader not waiting in async/await block - solved

Tags: nestjs, csvreader

I am using csvReader with nestjs and have the function in the 'on' event flagged as async and the save to DB marked with await.

The 'on' event does not appear to wait for the save to complete and prints log messages after processing the file.

The code is shown below:

```
const CsvReadableStream = require('csv-reader');
const Fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
@EntityRepository(UserTitle)
export class UserTitleRepository extends Repository<UserTitle> {
async seedUserTitle(): Promise<string> {
 // load titles
const basePath = __dirname.replace('/dist', '');
const filePath = path.join(basePath, 'titles.csv');
let inputStream = Fs.createReadStream(filePath, 'utf8');
let numRecs = 0;

inputStream
  .pipe(
    new CsvReadableStream({
      parseNumbers: true,
      parseBooleans: true,
      trim: true,
    }),
  )
  .on('data', async function (row: SeedTitleDto) {
    const seedTitle = new UserTitle();
    seedTitle.shortName = row[0];
    seedTitle.name = row[1];
    seedTitle.seq = row[2];

    try {
      await seedTitle.save();
      numRecs++;
      console.log(`Save ${numRecs}`);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        // duplicate username
        throw new ConflictException(
          `User Title ${seedTitle.shortName} already exists`,
        );
        return;
      } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message);
        return;
      }
    }
  })
  .on('end', function async(row: SeedTitleDto) {
    console.log(`End of file reached ${numRecs}`);
  });
  return `Created ${numRecs} titles`;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get this package to allow async processing?

Many thanks

Comment: this https://2ality.com/2018/04/async-iter-nodejs.html and this https://youtu.be/dEFdt_6fW-0?t=882 might help you

Comment: Thanks this is really useful and provides a way forward